# When is a moment generating function defined? (Probability)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a moment generating function m(t) = 1/(t+1). I believe moment generating functions are only defined for t values that produce a finite output. Would this imply that my m.g.f. is only defined over the interval (-1,∞)? Or is it less than that? How would I be able to determine which fractions produce a finite output and which do not?

If this is correct, why is a moment generating function said to be defined only for t values that produce a finite output? Assuming it did not run into issues where you are dividing by 0 as is the case here, what is the intuitive reason for requiring that the function only produce finite values?